# Tomcat auto-reload is not working on changing the class files in the context

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have the source code in one place and the tomcat in another place.

The source code directory used as the workspace for eclipse.

tomcat webapps has the WAR deployed therein.

I have setup my eclipse to copy newer compiled classes from the workspace to the webapps folder using a linked folder.

Now my problem is that : Upon the copying of the classes to the webapps, which is again marked as the watched resource in the context.xml, the tomcat is not auto-reloading the context with the newer classes. I have to do it manually all the time.

below is the snippet from my context.xml:

```
<Context crossContext="true" reloadable="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/service</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/utils</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/controller</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Are you using DEBUG mode? also If you add a new class or a new method, restart is still required.

Comment: @user7294900 Yeah I am using the DEBUG mode. Yeah true, the restart is required, but tomcat is configured for auto restart/reload, I assume I don't have to kill the tomcat engine and again start it to actually restart it. So I was looking for the auto restart feature of the tomcat which is not happening in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if `autoDeploy` is set to `"true"` of `<Host>` element in `server.xml`.

In addition, the following lines are not needed.

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/service</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/utils</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/classes/com/fmr/fit/pma/controller</WatchedResource>
```

Comment: I added those lines when I was trying to make the auto deploy feature work. I removed it anyways now, it seems it is not needed anyways.

     <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" startStopThreads="2">

autodeploy is true in server.xml for me. But somehow it has now started working all of a sudden. Thanks.

Comment: @SatyajitPatnaik Apparantly I am in the same situation, Checked all the configurations mentioned on this page and the general tomcat settings. but the webapp contents do not seem to hot reload.

Comment: I never could crack this anyway @NitinNanda
I eventually moved on to using Spring Boot Devtools which was more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<WatchedResource>/WEB-INF/classes/</WatchedResource>
```

worked for me. Note starting forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipse, make sure you have activated `Build Automatically` under `Project` tab so that it reloads tomcat upon saving.

[image]